# Il faut + verbe pronominal : quel pronom utiliser ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes-pronominaux

Dans la phrase :

> Mon petit, il faut (se/te) lever tôt.

Doit-on utiliser le pronom « se » ou « te » et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les deux se disent mais ne signifient pas tout à fait la même chose.

> Mon petit, il faut se lever tôt.

Cette phrase est une généralité. Tout le monde à intérêt à se lever tôt.

> Mon petit, il faut te lever tôt.

Cette phrase peut à nouveau être un conseil de tout les jours, mais adressé spécifiquement à « mon petit ». « Mon petit, tu as intérêt à te lever tôt tous les jours ».

Elle peut également signifier un remarque ponctuelle : Demain, tu dois te lever tôt.